# Unable to create table in the Snowflake using the pandas dataset

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to push the data from pandas to the Snowflake by establishing SSH key pair connection. But I'm getting the below error.

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer

from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

import pandas as pd
df_app = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=['A','B'])


passcode = 'xxxxxxx'

with open(r"C:\Users\rsa_key.p8", "rb") as key:
    p_key= serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key.read(),
        password=passcode.encode(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )

pkb = p_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption())

engine = create_engine(URL(
    account='snowflake_account',
    warehouse='snowflake_warehouse',
    database='snowflake_db',
    schema='snowlfake_workspace',
    user='snowflake_user'
    ),
    connect_args={
        'private_key': pkb,
    }
    )


df_app.to_sql(name='test_connect1'.lower(), con=engine, if_exists='replace', method=pd_writer,index=False)
```

I am getting below error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1704                 if not evt_handled:
-> 1705                     self.dialect.do_execute(
   1706                         cursor, statement, parameters, context

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    691     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 692         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    693 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\snowflake\connector\cursor.py in execute(self, command, params, _bind_stage, timeout, _exec_async, _no_retry, _do_reset, _put_callback, _put_azure_callback, _put_callback_output_stream, _get_callback, _get_azure_callback, _get_callback_output_stream, _show_progress_bar, _statement_params, _is_internal, _describe_only, _no_results, _is_put_get, _raise_put_get_error, _force_put_overwrite, file_stream)
    803             error_class = IntegrityError if is_integrity_error else ProgrammingError
--> 804             Error.errorhandler_wrapper(self.connection, self, error_class, errvalue)
    805         return self

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py in errorhandler_wrapper(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    275 
--> 276         handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(
    277             connection,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py in hand_to_other_handler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    330             cursor.messages.append((error_class, error_value))
--> 331             cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    332             return True

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py in default_errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    209         """
--> 210         raise error_class(
    211             msg=error_value.get("msg"),

ProgrammingError: 090105 (22000): Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.


~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py in hand_to_other_handler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    329         if cursor is not None:
    330             cursor.messages.append((error_class, error_value))
--> 331             cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    332             return True
    333         elif connection is not None:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py in default_errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    208             A Snowflake error.
    209         """
--> 210         raise error_class(
    211             msg=error_value.get("msg"),
    212             errno=error_value.get("errno"),

ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 090105 (22000): Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current database. Call 'USE DATABASE', or use a qualified name.
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE test_connect1 (
    "A" BIGINT, 
    "B" BIGINT
)

]
```

I verified the user has the write permission to create table and able to create the table directly in the snowflake in the workspace. But this issue is being observed when performed through the python connectivity. Please advice on this issue

Comment: The error: "Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current database." says that you do not have a DATABASE selected in your connection. You might want to add the role='role_name' properties in your connection to make sure that you use the same role as in your test in the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the Role parameter made it work. :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the confirmation. I've posted this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current
> database.

says that you do not have a DATABASE selected in the connection.

When it was confirmed that the user has been granted the role with the required permissions to operated on the database, the `role='role_name'` parameter must be added to the connection properties. Otherwise, the connection will be made with the default role assigned to the user (e.g. 'public') which might not always have the required permission on the selected database.